# App is crashing when loading new activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Hi im trying to load another acivity on my class without activity extension so I used another class that has an activity this is my code for the **MAINACTIVITY**

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
    if (null == savedInstanceState) {
      getFragmentManager()
              .beginTransaction()
              .replace(R.id.container, Camera2BasicFragment.newInstance())
              .commit();


    }


  }

  public void loadScanresults2() {

    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, resultsActvitity.class);
    intent1.putExtra("HighScanResults", GlobalVars.scanresHigh);
    intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    **startActivity(intent1);**


  }
```

and this is the class for ImageCLassifier

```
public class ImageClassifier {




  private static final String TAG = "TfLiteCameraDemo";


  private static final String MODEL_PATH = "graph.lite";


  private static final String LABEL_PATH = "labels.txt";


  private static final int RESULTS_TO_SHOW = 3;


  private static final int DIM_BATCH_SIZE = 1;

  private static final int DIM_PIXEL_SIZE = 3;

  static final int DIM_IMG_SIZE_X = 224;
  static final int DIM_IMG_SIZE_Y = 224;

  private static final int IMAGE_MEAN = 128;
  private static final float IMAGE_STD = 128.0f;

  private int[] intValues = new int[DIM_IMG_SIZE_X * DIM_IMG_SIZE_Y];

  private Interpreter tflite;

  private List<String> labelList;

  /** A ByteBuffer to hold image data, to be feed into Tensorflow Lite as inputs. */
  private ByteBuffer imgData = null;


  private float[][] labelProbArray = null;

  private float[][] filterLabelProbArray = null;
  private static final int FILTER_STAGES = 3;
  private static final float FILTER_FACTOR = 0.4f;

  private PriorityQueue<Map.Entry<String, Float>> sortedLabels =
      new PriorityQueue<>(
          RESULTS_TO_SHOW,
          new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Float>>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Float> o1, Map.Entry<String, Float> o2) {
              return (o1.getValue()).compareTo(o2.getValue());
            }
          });


  ImageClassifier(Activity activity) throws IOException {
    tflite = new Interpreter(loadModelFile(activity));
    labelList = loadLabelList(activity);
    imgData =
        ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
            4 * DIM_BATCH_SIZE * DIM_IMG_SIZE_X * DIM_IMG_SIZE_Y * DIM_PIXEL_SIZE);
    imgData.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    labelProbArray = new float[1][labelList.size()];
    filterLabelProbArray = new float[FILTER_STAGES][labelList.size()];
    Log.d(TAG, "Created a Tensorflow Lite Image Classifier.");
  }


  String classifyFrame(Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (tflite == null) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Image classifier has not been initialized; Skipped.");
      return "Uninitialized Classifier.";
    }
    convertBitmapToByteBuffer(bitmap);
    // Here's where the magic happens!!!
    long startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    tflite.run(imgData, labelProbArray);
    long endTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    Log.d(TAG, "Timecost to run model inference: " + Long.toString(endTime - startTime));

    // smooth the results
    applyFilter();

    // print the results
    String textToShow = printTopKLabels();
    textToShow = Long.toString(endTime - startTime) + "ms" + textToShow;
    return textToShow;
  }

  void applyFilter(){
    int num_labels =  labelList.size();

    // Low pass filter `labelProbArray` into the first stage of the filter.
    for(int j=0; j<num_labels; ++j){
      filterLabelProbArray[0][j] += FILTER_FACTOR*(labelProbArray[0][j] -
                                                   filterLabelProbArray[0][j]);
    }
    // Low pass filter each stage into the next.
    for (int i=1; i<FILTER_STAGES; ++i){
      for(int j=0; j<num_labels; ++j){
        filterLabelProbArray[i][j] += FILTER_FACTOR*(
                filterLabelProbArray[i-1][j] -
                filterLabelProbArray[i][j]);

      }
    }

    // Copy the last stage filter output back to `labelProbArray`.
    for(int j=0; j<num_labels; ++j){
      labelProbArray[0][j] = filterLabelProbArray[FILTER_STAGES-1][j];
    }
  }

  /** Closes tflite to release resources. */
  public void close() {
    tflite.close();
    tflite = null;
  }

  /** Reads label list from Assets. */
  private List<String> loadLabelList(Activity activity) throws IOException {
    List<String> labelList = new ArrayList<String>();
    BufferedReader reader =
        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(activity.getAssets().open(LABEL_PATH)));
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      labelList.add(line);
    }
    reader.close();
    return labelList;
  }

  /** Memory-map the model file in Assets. */
  private MappedByteBuffer loadModelFile(Activity activity) throws IOException {
    AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = activity.getAssets().openFd(MODEL_PATH);
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());
    FileChannel fileChannel = inputStream.getChannel();
    long startOffset = fileDescriptor.getStartOffset();
    long declaredLength = fileDescriptor.getDeclaredLength();
    return fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, startOffset, declaredLength);
  }

  /** Writes Image data into a {@code ByteBuffer}. */
  private void convertBitmapToByteBuffer(Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (imgData == null) {
      return;
    }
    imgData.rewind();
    bitmap.getPixels(intValues, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    // Convert the image to floating point.
    int pixel = 0;
    long startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < DIM_IMG_SIZE_X; ++i) {
      for (int j = 0; j < DIM_IMG_SIZE_Y; ++j) {
        final int val = intValues[pixel++];
        imgData.putFloat((((val >> 16) & 0xFF)-IMAGE_MEAN)/IMAGE_STD);
        imgData.putFloat((((val >> 8) & 0xFF)-IMAGE_MEAN)/IMAGE_STD);
        imgData.putFloat((((val) & 0xFF)-IMAGE_MEAN)/IMAGE_STD);
      }
    }
    long endTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    Log.d(TAG, "Timecost to put values into ByteBuffer: " + Long.toString(endTime - startTime));
  }

  /** Prints top-K labels, to be shown in UI as the results. */
  private String printTopKLabels() {
    for (int i = 0; i < labelList.size(); ++i) {
      sortedLabels.add(
              new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(labelList.get(i), labelProbArray[0][i]));
      if (sortedLabels.size() > RESULTS_TO_SHOW) {
        sortedLabels.poll();
      }

    }


    String textToShow = "";

   /* final int size = sortedLabels.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
*/


    Map.Entry<String, Float> label = sortedLabels.poll();

    //textToShow = String.format("\nHighest: %4.2f",labelProbArray[0][1]) + textToShow;
    textToShow = String.format("\nHighest: %4.2f", labelProbArray[0][1]) + textToShow;

    int list1 = 1;
    float f = labelProbArray[0][1];
    GlobalVars.reshigh = f;
    if (f > 0.95) {
      GlobalVars.scanresHigh = textToShow;
      GlobalVars.intentSet = true;
      textToShow = String.format("\nHighest: %4.2f %s ", labelProbArray[0][1], labelList.get(list1)) + textToShow;
      CameraActivity loadres = new CameraActivity();
      loadres.loadScanresults2();






    }

    return textToShow;


  }





  }
```

for the CameraFragment

```
/** Basic fragments for the Camera. */
public class Camera2BasicFragment extends Fragment
    implements FragmentCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {



  /** Tag for the {@link Log}. */
  private static final String TAG = "TfLiteCameraDemo";

  private static final String FRAGMENT_DIALOG = "dialog";

  private static final String HANDLE_THREAD_NAME = "CameraBackground";

  private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

  private final Object lock = new Object();
  private boolean runClassifier = false;
  private boolean checkedPermissions = false;
  private TextView textView;
  private ImageClassifier classifier;

  /** Max preview width that is guaranteed by Camera2 API */
  private static final int MAX_PREVIEW_WIDTH = 1920;

  /** Max preview height that is guaranteed by Camera2 API */
  private static final int MAX_PREVIEW_HEIGHT = 1080;

  /**
   * {@link TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener} handles several lifecycle events on a {@link
   * TextureView}.
   */
  private final TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener surfaceTextureListener =
      new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture texture, int width, int height) {
          openCamera(width, height);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture texture, int width, int height) {
          configureTransform(width, height);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture texture) {
          return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture texture) {}
      };

  /** ID of the current {@link CameraDevice}. */
  private String cameraId;


  private AutoFitTextureView textureView;

  private CameraCaptureSession captureSession;


  private CameraDevice cameraDevice;


  private Size previewSize;


  private final CameraDevice.StateCallback stateCallback =
      new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onOpened(@NonNull CameraDevice currentCameraDevice) {
          // This method is called when the camera is opened.  We start camera preview here.
          cameraOpenCloseLock.release();
          cameraDevice = currentCameraDevice;
          createCameraPreviewSession();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(@NonNull CameraDevice currentCameraDevice) {
          cameraOpenCloseLock.release();
          currentCameraDevice.close();
          cameraDevice = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(@NonNull CameraDevice currentCameraDevice, int error) {
          cameraOpenCloseLock.release();
          currentCameraDevice.close();
          cameraDevice = null;
          Activity activity = getActivity();
          if (null != activity) {
            activity.finish();
          }
        }
      };


  private HandlerThread backgroundThread;


  private Handler backgroundHandler;


  private ImageReader imageReader;


  private CaptureRequest.Builder previewRequestBuilder;


  private CaptureRequest previewRequest;


  private Semaphore cameraOpenCloseLock = new Semaphore(1);


  private CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback captureCallback =
      new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onCaptureProgressed(
            @NonNull CameraCaptureSession session,
            @NonNull CaptureRequest request,
            @NonNull CaptureResult partialResult) {}

        @Override
        public void onCaptureCompleted(
            @NonNull CameraCaptureSession session,
            @NonNull CaptureRequest request,
            @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {}
      };


  private void showToast(final String text) {
    final Activity activity = getActivity();
    if (activity != null) {
      activity.runOnUiThread(
          new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              textView.setText(text);
            }
          });
    }
  }


  private static Size chooseOptimalSize(
      Size[] choices,
      int textureViewWidth,
      int textureViewHeight,
      int maxWidth,
      int maxHeight,
      Size aspectRatio) {

    // Collect the supported resolutions that are at least as big as the preview Surface
    List<Size> bigEnough = new ArrayList<>();
    // Collect the supported resolutions that are smaller than the preview Surface
    List<Size> notBigEnough = new ArrayList<>();
    int w = aspectRatio.getWidth();
    int h = aspectRatio.getHeight();
    for (Size option : choices) {
      if (option.getWidth() <= maxWidth
          && option.getHeight() <= maxHeight
          && option.getHeight() == option.getWidth() * h / w) {
        if (option.getWidth() >= textureViewWidth && option.getHeight() >= textureViewHeight) {
          bigEnough.add(option);
        } else {
          notBigEnough.add(option);
        }
      }
    }

    // Pick the smallest of those big enough. If there is no one big enough, pick the
    // largest of those not big enough.
    if (bigEnough.size() > 0) {
      return Collections.min(bigEnough, new CompareSizesByArea());
    } else if (notBigEnough.size() > 0) {
      return Collections.max(notBigEnough, new CompareSizesByArea());
    } else {
      Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't find any suitable preview size");
      return choices[0];
    }
  }

  public static Camera2BasicFragment newInstance() {
    return new Camera2BasicFragment();
  }


  @Override
  public View onCreateView(
      LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_camera2_basic, container, false);
  }

  /** Connect the buttons to their event handler. */
  @Override
  public void onViewCreated(final View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    textureView = (AutoFitTextureView) view.findViewById(R.id.texture);
    textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);
  }


  @Override
  public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    try {
      classifier = new ImageClassifier(getActivity());
    } catch (IOException e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Failed to initialize an image classifier.");
    }
    startBackgroundThread();
  }

  @Override
  public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    startBackgroundThread();


    if (textureView.isAvailable()) {
      openCamera(textureView.getWidth(), textureView.getHeight());
    } else {
      textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(surfaceTextureListener);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onPause() {
    closeCamera();
    stopBackgroundThread();
    super.onPause();
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    classifier.close();
    super.onDestroy();
  }


  private void setUpCameraOutputs(int width, int height) {
    Activity activity = getActivity();
    CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
      for (String cameraId : manager.getCameraIdList()) {
        CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);

        // We don't use a front facing camera in this sample.
        Integer facing = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING);
        if (facing != null && facing == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT) {
          continue;
        }

        StreamConfigurationMap map =
            characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
        if (map == null) {
          continue;
        }


        Size largest =
            Collections.max(
                Arrays.asList(map.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG)), new CompareSizesByArea());
        imageReader =
            ImageReader.newInstance(
                largest.getWidth(), largest.getHeight(), ImageFormat.JPEG, /*maxImages*/ 2);


        int displayRotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();

        int sensorOrientation = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION);
        boolean swappedDimensions = false;
        switch (displayRotation) {
          case Surface.ROTATION_0:
          case Surface.ROTATION_180:
            if (sensorOrientation == 90 || sensorOrientation == 270) {
              swappedDimensions = true;
            }
            break;
          case Surface.ROTATION_90:
          case Surface.ROTATION_270:
            if (sensorOrientation == 0 || sensorOrientation == 180) {
              swappedDimensions = true;
            }
            break;
          default:
            Log.e(TAG, "Display rotation is invalid: " + displayRotation);
        }

        Point displaySize = new Point();
        activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(displaySize);
        int rotatedPreviewWidth = width;
        int rotatedPreviewHeight = height;
        int maxPreviewWidth = displaySize.x;
        int maxPreviewHeight = displaySize.y;

        if (swappedDimensions) {
          rotatedPreviewWidth = height;
          rotatedPreviewHeight = width;
          maxPreviewWidth = displaySize.y;
          maxPreviewHeight = displaySize.x;
        }

        if (maxPreviewWidth > MAX_PREVIEW_WIDTH) {
          maxPreviewWidth = MAX_PREVIEW_WIDTH;
        }

        if (maxPreviewHeight > MAX_PREVIEW_HEIGHT) {
          maxPreviewHeight = MAX_PREVIEW_HEIGHT;
        }

        previewSize =
            chooseOptimalSize(
                map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class),
                rotatedPreviewWidth,
                rotatedPreviewHeight,
                maxPreviewWidth,
                maxPreviewHeight,
                largest);

        // We fit the aspect ratio of TextureView to the size of preview we picked.
        int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
        if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
          textureView.setAspectRatio(previewSize.getWidth(), previewSize.getHeight());
        } else {
          textureView.setAspectRatio(previewSize.getHeight(), previewSize.getWidth());
        }

        this.cameraId = cameraId;
        return;
      }
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
      // Currently an NPE is thrown when the Camera2API is used but not supported on the
      // device this code runs.
      ErrorDialog.newInstance(getString(R.string.camera_error))
          .show(getChildFragmentManager(), FRAGMENT_DIALOG);
    }
  }

  private String[] getRequiredPermissions() {
    Activity activity = getActivity();
    try {
      PackageInfo info =
          activity
              .getPackageManager()
              .getPackageInfo(activity.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
      String[] ps = info.requestedPermissions;
      if (ps != null && ps.length > 0) {
        return ps;
      } else {
        return new String[0];
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      return new String[0];
    }
  }

  /** Opens the camera specified by {@link Camera2BasicFragment#cameraId}. */
  private void openCamera(int width, int height) {
    if (!checkedPermissions && !allPermissionsGranted()) {
      FragmentCompat.requestPermissions(this, getRequiredPermissions(), PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
      return;
    } else {
      checkedPermissions = true;
    }
    setUpCameraOutputs(width, height);
    configureTransform(width, height);
    Activity activity = getActivity();
    CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
      if (!cameraOpenCloseLock.tryAcquire(2500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Time out waiting to lock camera opening.");
      }
      manager.openCamera(cameraId, stateCallback, backgroundHandler);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted while trying to lock camera opening.", e);
    }
  }

  private boolean allPermissionsGranted() {
    for (String permission : getRequiredPermissions()) {
      if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), permission)
          != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public void onRequestPermissionsResult(
      int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
  }

  /** Closes the current {@link CameraDevice}. */
  private void closeCamera() {
    try {
      cameraOpenCloseLock.acquire();
      if (null != captureSession) {
        captureSession.close();
        captureSession = null;
      }
      if (null != cameraDevice) {
        cameraDevice.close();
        cameraDevice = null;
      }
      if (null != imageReader) {
        imageReader.close();
        imageReader = null;
      }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted while trying to lock camera closing.", e);
    } finally {
      cameraOpenCloseLock.release();
    }
  }

  /** Starts a background thread and its {@link Handler}. */
  private void startBackgroundThread() {
    backgroundThread = new HandlerThread(HANDLE_THREAD_NAME);
    backgroundThread.start();
    backgroundHandler = new Handler(backgroundThread.getLooper());
    synchronized (lock) {
      runClassifier = true;
    }
    backgroundHandler.post(periodicClassify);
  }

  /** Stops the background thread and its {@link Handler}. */
  private void stopBackgroundThread() {
    backgroundThread.quitSafely();
    try {
      backgroundThread.join();
      backgroundThread = null;
      backgroundHandler = null;
      synchronized (lock) {
        runClassifier = false;
      }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  /** Takes photos and classify them periodically. */
  private Runnable periodicClassify =
      new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          synchronized (lock) {
            if (runClassifier) {
              classifyFrame();
            }
          }
          backgroundHandler.post(periodicClassify);
        }
      };

  /** Creates a new {@link CameraCaptureSession} for camera preview. */
  private void createCameraPreviewSession() {
    try {
      SurfaceTexture texture = textureView.getSurfaceTexture();
      assert texture != null;

      // We configure the size of default buffer to be the size of camera preview we want.
      texture.setDefaultBufferSize(previewSize.getWidth(), previewSize.getHeight());

      // This is the output Surface we need to start preview.
      Surface surface = new Surface(texture);

      // We set up a CaptureRequest.Builder with the output Surface.
      previewRequestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
      previewRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);

      // Here, we create a CameraCaptureSession for camera preview.
      cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(
          Arrays.asList(surface),
          new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
              // The camera is already closed
              if (null == cameraDevice) {
                return;
              }

              // When the session is ready, we start displaying the preview.
              captureSession = cameraCaptureSession;
              try {
                // Auto focus should be continuous for camera preview.
                previewRequestBuilder.set(
                    CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,
                    CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);

                // Finally, we start displaying the camera preview.
                previewRequest = previewRequestBuilder.build();
                captureSession.setRepeatingRequest(
                    previewRequest, captureCallback, backgroundHandler);
              } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }
            }

            @Override
            public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
              showToast("Failed");
            }
          },
          null);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  /**
   * Configures the necessary {@link android.graphics.Matrix} transformation to `textureView`. This
   * method should be called after the camera preview size is determined in setUpCameraOutputs and
   * also the size of `textureView` is fixed.
   *
   * @param viewWidth The width of `textureView`
   * @param viewHeight The height of `textureView`
   */
  private void configureTransform(int viewWidth, int viewHeight) {
    Activity activity = getActivity();
    if (null == textureView || null == previewSize || null == activity) {
      return;
    }
    int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    RectF viewRect = new RectF(0, 0, viewWidth, viewHeight);
    RectF bufferRect = new RectF(0, 0, previewSize.getHeight(), previewSize.getWidth());
    float centerX = viewRect.centerX();
    float centerY = viewRect.centerY();
    if (Surface.ROTATION_90 == rotation || Surface.ROTATION_270 == rotation) {
      bufferRect.offset(centerX - bufferRect.centerX(), centerY - bufferRect.centerY());
      matrix.setRectToRect(viewRect, bufferRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);
      float scale =
          Math.max(
              (float) viewHeight / previewSize.getHeight(),
              (float) viewWidth / previewSize.getWidth());
      matrix.postScale(scale, scale, centerX, centerY);
      matrix.postRotate(90 * (rotation - 2), centerX, centerY);
    } else if (Surface.ROTATION_180 == rotation) {
      matrix.postRotate(180, centerX, centerY);
    }
    textureView.setTransform(matrix);
  }

  /** Classifies a frame from the preview stream. */
  private void classifyFrame() {
    if (classifier == null || getActivity() == null || cameraDevice == null) {
      showToast("Uninitialized Classifier or invalid context.");
      return;
    }
    Bitmap bitmap =
        textureView.getBitmap(ImageClassifier.DIM_IMG_SIZE_X, ImageClassifier.DIM_IMG_SIZE_Y);
    String textToShow = classifier.classifyFrame(bitmap);
    bitmap.recycle();
    showToast(textToShow);
  }

  /** Compares two {@code Size}s based on their areas. */
  private static class CompareSizesByArea implements Comparator<Size> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Size lhs, Size rhs) {
      // We cast here to ensure the multiplications won't overflow
      return Long.signum(
          (long) lhs.getWidth() * lhs.getHeight() - (long) rhs.getWidth() * rhs.getHeight());
    }
  }

  /** Shows an error message dialog. */
  public static class ErrorDialog extends DialogFragment {

    private static final String ARG_MESSAGE = "message";

    public static ErrorDialog newInstance(String message) {
      ErrorDialog dialog = new ErrorDialog();
      Bundle args = new Bundle();
      args.putString(ARG_MESSAGE, message);
      dialog.setArguments(args);
      return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      final Activity activity = getActivity();
      return new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
          .setMessage(getArguments().getString(ARG_MESSAGE))
          .setPositiveButton(
              android.R.string.ok,
              new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                  activity.finish();
                }
              })
          .create();
    }
  }

}
```

and this is the error that im getting whenever I run debug

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:132)
        at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:128)
        at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:4868)
        at com.example.android.tflitecamerademo.loadScanresults.loadScanresults2(loadScanresults.java:11)
        at com.example.android.tflitecamerademo.ImageClassifier.printTopKLabels(ImageClassifier.java:246)
        at com.example.android.tflitecamerademo.ImageClassifier.classifyFrame(ImageClassifier.java:134)
        at com.example.android.tflitecamerademo.Camera2BasicFragment.classifyFrame(Camera2BasicFragment.java:663)
        at com.example.android.tflitecamerademo.Camera2BasicFragment.access$900(Camera2BasicFragment.java:69)
        at com.example.android.tflitecamerademo.Camera2BasicFragment$5.run(Camera2BasicFragment.java:558)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

am I doing something wrong? thanks guys

EDIT: It's still having the same errors

Answer (score 0):

## DO NEVER HOLD A REFERENCE TO THE ACTIVITY LIKE THE OTHER ANSWER SUGGESTS

It'll only lead  to memory leaks because of how GC works.

You should **NOT** instantiate activities directly. Leave that to the OS. **That's why of your NPE**

Your new activity's context is not initialized therefore leading to this Exception

Something you might be looking aftet right now is this:

```
public class ResultsActivity extends Activity {
    public static void launch(Context ctx, float data){
          Intent i = new Intent(ctx, ResultsActivity.class);
          i.putExtra("extraData", data);
          ctx.startActivity(i);
    }


   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle b){
          float data = getIntent().getExtra("extraData");
    }
}
```

Use it like this assuming you're in a Activity:

```
ResultsActivity.launch(this, yourValue);
//finish(); this Activity? Maybe?
```

If you're not into another activity you will have to pass the context as a extra parameter through methods.

The ideal way of doing this would be to get the data back to the activity that fired "getting the data" and from there, start the new Activity

### Edit

If the UI component that you're using is a `Fragment` use the `onActivityCreated` lifecycle.

```
public class SomeFragment extends Fragments {

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle b) {
        // And to get a reference of the context here you can do:
        Context ctx = getContext();
    }

    private void onFaceDetected(float probability) {
        Context ctx = getContext();
        ResultsActivity.launch(ctx, probability); // for instance
    }
}
```

Comment: hi thanks i tried that but it game an error on the override part but please check my edited post it has the complete codes. thank you so much

Comment: If the component is a fragment, the method to override is not `onCreate` is `onActivityCreated`

Comment: Hi yes im already using that on Camera2Basicfragment on getactivity method for imageclassifier

Comment: Can you summarize a bit clearer what's wrong and indicate which line is the one crashing? I can't see the line numbers and I don't really want to go over 600 lines of code on a webbrowser with bad syntax highlighting :(

Comment: Hi again sorry for that the code is intended to scan an image and when it reaches a certain number of probability it will open another activity. The code that is giving an error is the startActivity method which is highlighted now. thanks again

Comment: it's on the mainactivity java

Comment: As stated from my answer on the top part.

You should NOT instantiate activities directly. Leave that to the OS. That's why of your NullPointerException (NPE)

Your new activity's context is not initialized therefore leading to this NullPointerException.

Basically what you're doing: 
Create a new Activity -> Call a method on that object -> that method accesses the Context property which is not initialized by the OS (when you pas `this`to the intent constr) -> NullPointerException

What you really want:
From Any Context, call startActivity -> pass the intent with extra data -> profit